# Scrapy Spider retry request

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

On occasion I'll have a response with unexpected html and all of the item fields will not be extracted, however, if I retry the request, it will typically return the expected html.

As a quick fix I'm catching the error in the spiders `parse` method:

```
# project/spiders/sample_spider.py

class SampleSpider(Spider):

    [...]

    def parse(self, response):
        try:
            item = SampleItem()

            item['sample_1'] = response.xpath('sample').extract()
            item['product_count_2'] = response.xpath('sample').extract()[0]

            yield item
        except IndexError:
            logger.debug('Retrying %(url)s', {'url': response.url})
            yield Request(response.url, self.parse, dont_filter=True)
```

I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32664022/scrapy-crawlspider-retry-scrape) which appears to be a similar scenario, but it seems this type of error should be handled in a Item Pipeline... Any thoughts on the best way to implement this fix?

Comment: Why does it fail, network error or what exactly?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, it's returns with a 200 response, but it just doesn't return the expected html for some reason.

Comment: What html is returned?

Comment: The urls that are being requested are search queries and it returns a page that states my search did not return any results.

Comment: The query is of coarse valid, as retrying the request returns the expected html.

Comment: That is strange that it succeeds intermittently, you could do as you suggest and create some pipeline that would retry but really getting to the underlying reason would be a better option,can you share the site?

Comment: Amazon, typically this is the offending http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dfashion&field-keywords=%22+%22

Comment: what are you trying to scrape?

Comment: "1-48 of 32,964,255 results for Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry"

Comment: Are you actually using that url?

Comment: Yes, that's typically the url that needs to retried.

Comment: The url you had posted did not actually work

Comment: Hmm, try this http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dfashion&field-keywords=%22+%22